# a secure password VS a strong password

Tags: difference

I wonder whether **a secure password** and **a strong password** are synonyms or not.
Could you tell me please the difference between them?

Comment: https://security.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

“Strong password” will likely be used if you have an algorithm that measures password strength. But such algorithms can be wrong, and a “strong” password may be insecure. “Secure password” is a password that is actually secure.

For example, a password may be very strong, 20 letters and digits. But if you use the same strong password on many sites, and one of those sites is careless and leaks your password, then it is still strong but not secure anymore.

Answer (score 1):

The terms are often used as synonyms, but they indeed have slightly different implications.

A strong password typically refers to a password that is difficult for others to guess or crack through automated methods (such as brute force) involving a combination of letters, numbers, special characters, and length.

A secure password is a broader concept, taking into account additional factors, such as management practices and the overall security of the accounts it protects. In other words, it adds the way that the password is managed and protected (for example, how many times you change your password, if you share it with other people, where you store it).

Even though is hard to affirm that a password is 100% safe, MFA and password managers help with security. Basically, combining both strength and good security practices is your best bet to keeping it safe online.

Answer (score 0):

The two are often used interchangeably, but they're not the same. A "strong password" is one that's relatively difficult to guess by brute force.

There's no such thing as a "secure password" because no password is truly secure. All passwords have vulnerabilities, including being phished.

I don't know what the context is you're talking about but "strong password" is almost certainly the better choice.